# Select the latest NEW rows by Date from the Snapshot Table

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-synapse

I have a snapshot table like the following

| id | name | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC Corp | 500 | yesterday |
| 123 | ABC Corp | 500 | today |
| 456 | XYZ Ltd. | 700 | today |
| 123 | ABC Corp | 500 | tomorrow |
| 456 | XYZ Ltd. | 700 | tomorrow |
| 789 | PQR Consulting | 100 | tomorrow |

I would like to get the new rows only like the following table from the above snapshot table using sql

| id | name | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 456 | XYZ Ltd. | 700 | today |
| 789 | PQR Consulting | 100 | tomorrow |

I need a pointer whether to follow the window function (like LAG() etc.) to get the new table. or more simple solution is there? Thanks in advance!

Comment: SQL Server <> PostgreSQL - please correct your tags. And showing us what you have tried won't be a bad thing either.

Comment: Wonder the data type for the date column. If the value is like what you wrote, yesterday, today or tomorrow, the latest means all rows ala. it is tomorrow?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: @learning yes, date column is a date field with actual datetimestamp

Comment: @Dale K - I tried to use LAG function like the following - LAG(COUNT(id)) OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY date). But I am getting the SUM of the count of new rows at each snapshot date, not the original new rows. Please help!

Comment: What are the possible values in your "Date" column? ('yesterday', 'today' and 'tomorrow' are not dates)

Comment: @ZoharPeled - The date column is the actual date field like '2022-10-12' instead of today, '2022-10-11' instead of yesterday and so on.

Comment: You can use group by in SQL script. 
`select id,name,value,max(date) as date from input_table group by id,name,value`

Comment: @Aswin this group by will only be good as long as the value never changes between dates...

Comment: @Aswin Right, that may also be a solution. But wont it be MIN instead of MAX since we want to capture the first date it was included in the snapshot table?

Comment: @Neel use max function, if you want to capture for latest date. or use min only for the earliest date

Comment: @Aswin - I tried your method, but it didnt work. I am seeing random duplicates in the new table

Comment: @Neel Could u share the exact requirement and desired results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options here, one of them is to use a cte or a derived table to add `row_number` based on the date column to the table, and the other is to use `first_value` window function. I'm pretty sure the derived table solution would be better in terms of performance, but I don't have the time to test.
Here's what I would do:

```sql
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT id, name, value, date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) as rn
    FROM snapshotTable
)
SELECT id, name, value, date
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

To get the earliest records all you need to do is remove the `DESC` from the `order by` clause.